# Problem with pulling data from Graphql into Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm pretty new here to gatsby/programming and i was playing around with the gatsby. I have below issue and I would appreciate if you could let me know where does it goes wrong? Below is my code.

Problem 1: Why i can't return/access the {post1.categories.nodes.name} ? It shows nothing on my page.

Note that there was no problem for me to access {post.video.videoSource} so i guess my Graphql worked fine but when i tried with {post1.categories.nodes.name}, it was literally blank.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

```
const BlogIndex = ({
  data,
  pageContext: { nextPagePath, previousPagePath },
}) => {
  const posts = data.allWpPost.nodes

  if (!posts.length) {
    return (
      <Layout isHomePage>
        <Seo title="All posts" />
        <Bio />
        <p>
          No blog posts found. Add posts to your WordPress site and they'll
          appear here!
        </p>
      </Layout>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Layout isHomePage>
      <Seo title="All posts" />

      {/* <Bio /> */}

      <Grid container rowSpacing={5} column spacing={5}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={3} md={3} lg={3}>
          <Paper>
            <ol style={{ listStyle: `none` }}>
              {posts.map(post1 => {
                return <li>{post1.categories.nodes.name}</li>
              })}
            </ol>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm={9} md={9} lg={9}>
          <Paper>
            <ol style={{ listStyle: `none` }}>
              {posts.map(post => {
                const hasVideoUrl = post.video.videoSource

                if (hasVideoUrl !== null) {
                  return (
                    <li key={post.uri}>
                      <article
                        className="post-list-item"
                        itemScope
                        itemType="http://schema.org/Article"
                      >
                        <header>
                          <small>{post.video.videoSource}</small>
                          <small>{post.video.videoUrl}</small>
                          {/* <ReactPlayer url={post.video.videoUrl} /> */}
                        </header>
                      </article>
                    </li>
                  )
                } else {
                  return null
                }
              })}
            </ol>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      {previousPagePath && (
        <>
          <Link to={previousPagePath}>Previous page</Link>
          <br />
        </>
      )}
      {nextPagePath && <Link to={nextPagePath}>Next page</Link>}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default BlogIndex

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query WordPressPostArchive($offset: Int!, $postsPerPage: Int!) {
    allWpPost(
      sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }
      limit: $postsPerPage
      skip: $offset
    ) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        uri
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        title
        video {
          videoSource
          videoUrl
        }
        categories {
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Problem 2 [Added 2 July 2022]:

```
       <ul>
          {wpPosts.map(wpPost => {
            wpPost.tags.nodes.map(tag => {
              console.log(tag.name)

              if (tag.name === "Blog") {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <li>{tag.title}</li>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            })
          })}
        </ul>



  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allWpPost(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }, limit: 10) {
          nodes {
            excerpt
            slug
            uri
            video {
              videoTitle
              videoUrl
            }
            title
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            tags {
              nodes {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const wpPosts = data.allWpPost.nodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem 1: Why i can't return/access the {post1.categories.nodes.name}
> ? It shows nothing on my page.

`nodes` (in `post1.categories.nodes.name`) is likely to be an array, so you will need to loop through it or access a specific position:

```
return <li>{post1.categories.nodes[0].name}</li>
```

Depending on your data structure you'll need to loop or just access to the first position. Without knowing your data it's difficult to guess.

Comment: Hi Ferran, your solution worked well ! Thank you very much.

Comment: But i'm curious to know why it worked that way. I've already Map () the nodes, isn't that a loop too?

Comment: You have two arrays, (two `nodes`),  the posts (`data.allWpPost.nodes`) and the categories (`categories.nodes`) so in order to display the data you will need to nest two maps (or to get the `[0]` in the second one)

Comment: Open a new question with the needed details/scope. It will get better audience than editing an already answered question.